# loop from cell i to last cell non-empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, I want to loop from cell i to the last non-empty cell. But I keep getting a type mismatch error even though I am declaring it the same type.

```
Dim wsList as Worksheet
Dim wsCode as Worksheet

Dim i as Variant
Dim j as Long

Dim LastCell as Variant
Dim LastCell2 as Long

With wsList 
    LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp) 
    LastCell2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)
End With

    For i = 1 To LastCell
        wsList.Range("G2").Offset(i - 1).Copy _
            wsCode.Range("C2").Offset((i - 1) * 14)
    Next i

    For j = 1 To LastCell2
        wsCode.Range("F11").Offset((j - 1) * 14).Value = _
            wsList.Range("F2").Offset(j - 1).Value
    Next j

End Sub
```

Mismatch error occurs between LastCell and i even though I declared them both as variant. I also tried declaring them as string but still getting the same error. The data type in that particular column is "AB12345" including quotation marks. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is `xlUp` not `x1Up`

Comment: It's in the correct format in my code, just messed it up as I was copying it here.

Comment: it should be `LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row` and `LastCell2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row` and declare them both as `Long`

Comment: [Finding last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Turns out you were right! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you're missing a `.row`. [It would be best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/51689021#51689021) to define all your row variables as `Long`. One other thing to consider is that your method of using `end(xlUP)` will not account for any rows that are hidden. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) discusses a variety of ways to address this.

```
With wsList 
    LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row
    LastCell2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
End With
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! variant type was okay for both. I will look over the links you mentioned but for now I am not worried about hidden rows as my current sheet doesn't have any hidden rows.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change

```
Dim LastCell as Variant
```

To

```
Dim LastCell as Long
```

Also, you should clearly identify the sheets for **wsList** and **wsCode**.

Comment: No.  OP doesn't define .row at end of statement. Variant would be fine.

Comment: Declaring them Variant and Long doesn't work either. And I have set wsList and wsCode in the workbook.  There is no mismatch between j and LastCell2 as that column contains numbers. But column G is formatted as "AB12345" as I mentioned.

Comment: Can you show all of the code, including where you're setting the variables for wsList and wsCode?

Comment: The other answer worked! Thanks for your input I appreciate it :)